# Model Missing Definition Error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am stuck trying to create a simple Bootstrap Table with ASP.NET MVC that pulls all records from a database but I cannot figure out why I am getting the error:

> CS1061: Model does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type Model could be found

My model:

```
public class AdminModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Admin ID")]
    public int AdminID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@model RuciyanaSweets.Models.AdminModel

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10">No Record's found.</td>
            </tr>

        }
        Else
<show the table>
        </table>
</div>
```

My control:

```
public ActionResult AdminList()
{
    List<AdminModel> qry = new List<AdminModel>();

    using (dbEntities dm = new dbEntities ())
    {
        qry = (from data in dm.AdminTables select new AdminModel
               {
                   AdminID = data.AdminId,
                   UserName = data.UserName,
                   FirstName = data.FirstName,
                   LastName = data.LastName
               }).ToList();
    }

    return View(qry);
}
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing collection of the `AdminModel` to the view. Therefore use the following model definition:

```
@model IEnumerable<AdminModel>
```

[Enumerable.Count Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Thanks!  I am still confused in regards to when I should or should not use IEnumberable, but your answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Rayman Bacchus: You just need to realize when you have one object or when you processing collection of objects. In the last case to use `IEnumerable<>`.